# List of possible emojis for Twitter

Tags: twitter, emoji

When using the Twitter API you get emojis as unicode characters. You can then easily parse out and display emojis as pictures. One example of such a parsing tool is [Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji), which is the official emoji parsing tool from Twitter. In the [twemoji.js](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/blob/gh-pages/twemoji.js) file there is a long regular expression they use to parse out the emojis.

However, this file has not been updated in two years, and there are many emojis missing from Twemoji that are displayed just fine on twitter.com.

Does anybody know of any other well maintained list of current emojis supported by twitter.com? A bonus would be that they use/provide a regular expression I can import into my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twemoji has a somewhat weird structure on Github due to a CDN mirroring, which means that when Twemoji releases a new version, or updates the regular expression in newer versions, the original versions will still be there.

The `twemoji.js` file on the front page is indeed an old version. However, they have released newer versions, so on the root of the project there is currently a folder named `2`. This file contains a `twemoji.js` that is much newer than the one at the root level. The regex in this file catches all emojis currently displayed on twitter.com.

So when getting a new regex for your app, remember to *not* check the root folder, but look for a numerical folder which contain newer versions.